# Using wso2id: what if receiver is down?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

we have set up two wso2-id servers and have them talk scim. When I create a user in the source wso2 it is 'scim-ed' to the target.

Now what would happen if:
1. the target wso2 would be down for some time and during this time one would create a new user in the source wso2?
2. one would modify user details (update password, create new user) directly in the AD, thus by passing the wso2-ui? Would this change still be send to the target using scim?

Hope to hear.

Answer (score 0):

In the current WSO2IS scim implementation.(WSo2IS 4.6.0)
01.If the SCIM provider (target) is down, if any operation happened in that time it will not provision after it start up.
02. If you directly change in user attribute in AD it want propagate through SCIM, but if you do it through user interface or through SCIM operation it will propagate.

Comment: Ok thank you. Doesn't this make the wso2is unusable for corporate production use? How should we implement wso2is for corporate usage?

Comment: You need to write a JMS based listener there. This is not shipped by default with the product and we are planning ship with the product in the future. Regarding your second questions - you should not try to edit uses details from the AD - if you do that you need to write some kind of a handler there to notify IS.